# Save XML file with XStream

Tags: java, xstream

I use `XStream` to write an object in a `xml file`. 
Then I deserializing the file again to use the objects. 
My Problem is, that after I close my program, the xml "file" is gone. So how can I save this xml file to a specific directory? I already tried `FileOutputStream` but it doesn't work... I also google it, but found not the right solution for me...

Method **savePerson**

```
public void savePerson(String uNummer, Person person) {
    System.out.println("save person");
    try{            
        xml = xstream.toXML(person);

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error in XML Write: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And the Method **readPerson**

```
public Person readPerson(String uNummer) {
    System.out.println("read person");
     Person person = new Person();
    try{
        person = (Person) xstream.fromXML(file_path + uNummer + ".xml");       
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error in XML Read: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return person;
}
```

**Directory**: `\\releasearea\ToolReleaseArea\PersistenceSave`

**EDIT** 
**Correct Code**: (by **ppeterka**)

```
public void savePerson(String uNummer, Person person) {
    System.out.println("save person XML");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try{            
        xml = xstream.toXML(person);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file_path + uNummer + ".xml");
        fos.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] bytes = xml.getBytes("UTF-8");
        fos.write(bytes);

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error in XML Write: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        if(fos != null){
            try{
                fos.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the file writing code? You only posted the serialization to string. You said you tried with a FileWriter; that should work

Comment: no, my FileWriter solution doesn't work... But ok, i post the code which i try...

Comment: Don't bother, ppterka answer's code should work

Comment: Just edited it :) Now i try his answer

Comment: ObjectOutputStream is used for java objects serialization; it has nothing to do with XML.In fact it writes down binary data to the output stream

Comment: Before i used xstream, i write the object's in .ser files. and it works with ObjectOutputStream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't write the file, just obtained the serialized content...

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("myfilename");
    fos.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>".getBytes("UTF-8")); //write XML header, as XStream doesn't do that for us
    byte[] bytes = xml.getBytes("UTF-8");
    fos.write(bytes);

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // this obviously needs to be refined.
} finally {
    if(fos!=null) {
        try{ 
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // this obviously needs to be refined.
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your reading function has an error too: the `xstream.fromXML(String)` accepts a `String`, but it does not interpret it as a file name, but as the XML content itself... You have to use the `fromXML(File)` function:

```
public Person readPerson(String uNummer) {
    System.out.println("read person");
    Person person = new Person(); //if there is an error during deserialization, this is going to be returned, is this what you want?
    try{
        File xmlFile = new File(file_path + uNummer + ".xml");
        person = (Person) xstream.fromXML(xmlFile);       
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error in XML Read: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return person;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to prepend the XML declaration as XStream omits it. From Xstream FAQ : "XStream is designed to write XML snippets, so you can embed its output into an existing stream or string. You can write the XML declaration yourself into the Writer before using it to call XStream.toXML(writer)."

Comment: Cool, it works :)
I post the correct Code for my specific programm. But i don't understand everything in your code, so can you help and explain it? So  what do byte[] bytes = xml.getBytes("UTF-8"); ? Don't understand this really...

Comment: That is just a datatype conversion. A String has to be converted to bytes before writing to a file. And it is wise to explicitly specify the character encoding, because the default encoding can vary from system to system.

Comment: Sorry when i ask again, but XStream is completely new for me... Now my Method readPerson doesn't work. The Error: 
only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not / (position: START_DOCUMENT seen /... @1:1) ...?

Comment: yes i can SAVE the xml. But what is now with READ? I become a error

Comment: @dTDesign: In my answer, you can find a new `readPerson()` function, does that give an error? If yes, what kind of error?

Comment: YOU ROCK! Cool now it works. And sorry for my dumb question. It was a a easy fault... 
Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

Use the overloaded method toXML(Object o, Writer w) to serialize directly to a file.
The toXML method you are using doesn't save to a file.

```
xstream.toXML(person, new FileWriter(file));
```

Answer (score 0):

Im doing like this is working well :

```
//Your Stream things...

    String xml = xstream.toXML(type);

        System.out.println(xml);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(xml));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.xml",
                true));

        while ((xml = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            writer.write(xml + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        }

        writer.close()
```

;

And output is :

```
<type>
  <OBJECT__TYPE>sdfsdf</OBJECT__TYPE>
  <prop>
    <DESCRIPTION>hfh</DESCRIPTION>
    <PARENT>NULL</PARENT>
    <VIRTUAL>0</VIRTUAL>
    <VISIBLE>1</VISIBLE>
    <PICTURE>NULL</PICTURE>
    <HELP>345345</HELP>
    <MIN__NO>NULL</MIN__NO>
    <MAX__NO>1</MAX__NO>
    <NAME__FORMAT>NULL</NAME__FORMAT>
  </prop>
</type>
<type>
  <OBJECT__TYPE>test</OBJECT__TYPE>
  <prop>
    <DESCRIPTION>test</DESCRIPTION>
    <PARENT>NULL</PARENT>
    <VIRTUAL>0</VIRTUAL>
    <VISIBLE>0</VISIBLE>
    <PICTURE>NULL</PICTURE>
    <HELP>noe</HELP>
    <MIN__NO>NULL</MIN__NO>
    <MAX__NO>NULL</MAX__NO>
    <NAME__FORMAT>5475</NAME__FORMAT>
  </prop>
</type>
```