# omitting xml declaration in xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to append content to xml using xstream but using xstream.toXml(obj,writer) every time I run this, it is adding xml declaration to the content, can we omit xml declaration in xstream?

Comment: What XML declaration, can you show code?

Comment: @eipark He (presumably) means the XML 'header line' declaration <?xml version="1.0"?>. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue (using XStream 1.4.4). The problem occurs if you use the StaxDriver instead of the JAXP DOM one or the default XPP3 one. So either switch to:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
```

(with the XPP3 and xmlpull JARs on the classpath) or

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
```

instead of

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
```

This is presumably a (consistency) bug in XStream, since its [FAQ explicitly states](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#XML) that it is for writing snippets and doesn't produce the XML declaration (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063815)). It provides no methods/settings to not produce it because it should never be produced! I will look into raising it with them.

Comment: It also doesn't pretty-print it when using the StAX driver either :-(

Comment: Just posted on the XStream mailing list about this (as Stuart Rossiter, my evil alter-ego): http://xstream.codehaus.org/list-user.html. Can't access their bug tracking system currently to raise it. May take a bit for it to appear in the browser...

Comment: After a longish discussion on the mailing list, they agreed that it's an issue. See the bug report: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XSTR-734

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime the XStream team is fixing the issue, you may do a workaround. Override the `createStaxWriter` in `StaxDriver`:

```
    StaxDriver driver = new StaxDriver() {
        @Override
        public StaxWriter createStaxWriter(XMLStreamWriter out) throws XMLStreamException {
            //the boolean parameter controls the production of XML declaration
            return createStaxWriter(out, false);  
        }
    };
    XStream xstream = new XStream(driver);
```