# XStream(new StaxDriver()) without XML declaration

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

### My program JAVA:

```
public static String toXml() {
KtpMessage ktpMessage =new KtpMessage();
ktpMessage.setdetails("test");
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
String objectXml = xstream.toXML(ktpMessage);
return objectXml;
```

---

The result is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><myclasses.Message><details>test</details></myclasses.Message>
```

my problem:
I want to generate the "objectXml" but without `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`
how can I do that ?

i want have this result:

```
<myclasses.Message><details>test</details></myclasses.Message>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/24951921/2197088, an idea similar to the one below, but ... well you will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your own [StaxWriter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/xml/StaxWriter.html) you can use the constructor that tells it not to write the `startDocument` StAX event (which is what creates the XML declaration).  Something like this (exception handling omitted):

```
StaxDriver drv = new StaxDriver();
XStream xstream = new XStream(drv);
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
StaxWriter sw = new StaxWriter(drv.getQnameMap(),
   drv.getOutputFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(strWriter),
   false, // don't do startDocument
   true); // do repair namespaces
xstream.marshal(ktpMessage, sw);
sw.close();
String objectXml = strWriter.toString();
```